# javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find SQL table for type: XXXXXX

Tags: ignite

I am using ignite 2.7 version and getting the below exception while querying the ignite cache:

```
19/10/30 05:33:14 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find SQL table for type: CanonicalXXXXX
javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find SQL table for type: CanonicalXXXXX
```

This is my code to start ignite:

```
def getIgnite(): Ignite = {
  val clusterName = clusterProperties.getProperty("XXXXXXXX")

  Ignition.setClientMode(true)

  try {
   val ignite = Ignition.ignite(clusterName);
   if ( clusterName == ignite.name() ) {
      logInfo("@@@@ Found and returning client for cluster: " + 
      clusterName)
      return ignite
   }
 }
  catch {
   case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
 }

 val configFilePath = clusterProperties.getProperty("XXXXXXXX")
 logInfo("@@@@ configFilePath: " + configFilePath)
 val configInputStream = FileSystem.get(new Configuration()).open(new 
 Path(configFilePath));

 logInfo("@@@@ Starting Ignite Client")
 return Ignition.start(configInputStream)    }
```

I am loading data into the cache and data get loaded successfully and cache size also get printed as below:

```
INFO dataloader.IgniteDataLoader: @@@@ OFFICIAL_NAME_CACHE SIZE => 51016471
```

Below code is for accessing the cache:

```
def createXXXXXXCache: IgniteCache[String, CanonicalXXXXX] = {
   val orgCacheCfg: CacheConfiguration[String, CanonicalXXXXX] =
   new CacheConfiguration[String, CanonicalXXXXX](OFFICIAL_NAME_CACHE)
   orgCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(classOf[String], classOf[CanonicalXXXXX])
   orgCacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
   orgCacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC)
   orgCacheCfg.setBackups(3)
   getIgnite().getOrCreateCache(orgCacheCfg)    }
```

But while trying to query the cache I am getting the exception. Below code is for querying the cache:

```
val companyName = "SUFFOLK CONST CO"
val queryString = "orgName = '" + companyName + "'"
val companyNameQuery = new SqlQuery[String, CanonicalXXXXX] 
(classOf[CanonicalXXXXX], queryString)
val queryCursor = igniteXXXXXX.createXXXXXXCache.query(companyNameQuery)
val queryResults = Future {
  queryCursor.getAll()
}
try {
  val companyResults = extractXXXXXVO(queryResults)
  logInfo(s"Ignite Results returned - $companyResults")
} catch {
  case exe: Exception => logInfo(s"OfficialXXXX exact search timed out")
  queryCursor.close()
  Vector.empty
}
```

The code throwing exception at query() method for the below line:

```
val queryCursor = igniteXXXXXX.createXXXXXXCache.query(companyNameQuery)

19/10/30 05:33:14 INFO dataloader.IgniteServerXXXXXX: Examplelogger1 - 'SqlQuery [type= CanonicalXXXXX, alias=null, sql=orgName = 'SUFFOLK CONSTRUCTION CO INC', args=null, timeout=0, distributedJoins=false, replicatedOnly=false]'
19/10/30 05:33:14 INFO dataloader.igniteXXXXXX: @@@@ Found and returning client for cluster: JalaDalaXXXXX
19/10/30 05:33:14 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find SQL table for type: CanonicalXXXXX
javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find SQL table for type: CanonicalXXXXX
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:697)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:376)
        at xx.xx.dataloader.IgniteServerXXXXXX$.loadOAData(IgniteServerXXXXXX.scala:70)
        at xx.xx.StartXXXXXXX$.startIgniteAndDataloading(StartXXXXXXX.scala:49)
        at xx.xx.StartXXXXXXX$delayedInit$body.apply(StartXXXXXXX.scala:13)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
        at xx.xx.StartXXXXXXX$.main(StartXXXXXXX.scala:12)
        at xx.xx.StartXXXXXXX.main(StartXXXXXXX.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:567)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed to find SQL table for type: CanonicalNameOAVO
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSql(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1843)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$7.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2289)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$7.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2287)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2707)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.queryDistributedSql(GridQueryProcessor.java:2286)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySql(GridQueryProcessor.java:2267)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:682)
```

Could someone please suggest how to resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Chandan

Comment: I have added some formatting to your question making it more readable for the reader. Try to format all code blocks and error messages next time to make your question more friendly and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the root cause of the issue, but first of all you should replace

```scala
val queryString = "orgName = '" + companyName + "'"
val companyNameQuery = new SqlQuery[String, CanonicalXXXXX](classOf[CanonicalXXXXX], queryString)
```

with

```scala
val queryString = "orgName = ?"
val companyNameQuery = new SqlQuery[String, CanonicalXXXXX](classOf[CanonicalXXXXX], queryString)
companyNameQuery.setArgs(companyName)
```

That's the correct way of using of this API. By the way [SqlQuery](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/SqlQuery.html) is a kind of deprecated stuff. You should prefer to use [SqlFieldsQuery](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/SqlFieldsQuery.html) instead of it.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to try SqlFieldsQuery of `SELECT _VAL FROM CanonicalXXXXX WHERE orgName = ?`